# My Angular UI isn't updating based on the List I am getting back from my HTTP GET request from my .Net Core API

Tags: angular, list, asp.net-core

I have an application that is Angular frontend and .Net Core API 3.0. I am trying to show a list of clients in the angular material grid. So on ngOnInit() I call my getAllClients service and bind my list to the result of my query but the UI doesnt update

```
 <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let client of clientList">
    <div class="clientEntry">
      {{client | json}}
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
```

When I do whats shown above it shows my objects in json format but I cant extrapolate the individual variables from the object by using ex. {{client.ClientName}}. When I use this I just end up with blank rows and cannot figure out what is going on.

My Package.json is below

```
{
  "name": "patocrm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run PatoCRM:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.26",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

Below is my Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ClientViewModel>> Get()
    {
        using (var db =  new Context())
        {
            var list = await db.Client.Include( x => x.SeoPlan).Include(x => x.WebPlan).Select(x => new ClientViewModel
            {
                ClientId = x.ClientId,
                ClientName = x.ClientName,
                BusinessName = x.BusinessName,
                PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber,
                BusinessAddress  =x.BusinessAddress,
                Email = x.Email,
                DateOfPayment = x.DateOfPayment,
                WebsiteUrl = x.WebsiteUrl,
                Notes = x.Notes,
                SeoPlanId = x.SeoPlanId,
                SeoPlanRank = x.SeoPlan.PlanRank,
                SeoPlanPrice = x.SeoPlan.PlanPrice,
                WebPlanId = x.WebPlanId,
                WebPlanRank = x.WebPlan.PlanRank,
                WebPlanPrice = x.WebPlan.PlanPrice
            }).ToListAsync();

           return list;
        }
    }
```

Below is my angular component followed by the ts model im using

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServicesService} from '../services/services.service';
import { Client } from '../models/client.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-grid',
  templateUrl: './client-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-grid.component.css']
})
export class ClientGridComponent implements OnInit {

  clientList: Client[]

  constructor(public HttpClient: HttpClient, private services : ServicesService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients() 
  }

  getClients() {
    this.services.getAllClients().subscribe(res => {
      this.clientList = res;
    },
      error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      });  
  }

}
```

This is the service I am using

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicesService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAllClients(): any {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://localhost:44317/api/Client'); 
  }
}
```

I have been stuck on this for a few days and dont understand why it wont update my UI, I have a feeling it could be im not returning the correct type of object or I need to use an observable but please any help will be appraciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{client.clientName}} try first letter lowercase

Comment: I appreciate the answer changing my model.ts and the value in the double brackets to lowercase fixed it. Why is this the case? is this a typescript thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can chose to explicitly update UI using `ChangeDetectorRef`

```js
  constructor(
    private readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private readonly services: ServicesService
  ) {}

  public getClients(): void {
    this.services.getAllClients().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.clientList = res;
        // Update UI now
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your response but this did not not fix my issue, i still see blank rows